# Can't Connect to RDS mysql DB from Wordpress on Ubuntu 18.04 EC2 Instance

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm trying to run Wordpress on my Ec2 instance with RDS MySQL database.

Here's the tutorial I've followed https://cristianocastro.net/instalando-wordpress-em-um-servidor-amazon-aws-pt-2-3/

But when I try to access the Ec2 instance that connect to the RDS on the browser it shows this message

```
Error establishing a database connection
```

I put in the security group inbound and outbound all traffic anywhere.

Here's the print from my security group rule.

[image]

Appreciate the help

PS: Saw this question, with no anwser [Can't Connect to RDS mysql DB from Wordpress on Amazon linux EC2 Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61280704/cant-connect-to-rds-mysql-db-from-wordpress-on-amazon-linux-ec2-instance)

Edit: Rules from security group of the ec2 instance that will access RDS.

[image]

Comment: Are you connecting to the RDS over internet? Is it publicly available? If not, is it in the same VPC as your instance?

Comment: Is the security group you posted the RDS one? If so, can you share also the entries of the one associated with the EC2?

Comment: @Marcin yes, I'm trying over internet. And also yes. And it's in the same VPC

Comment: @Andre.IDK yes. And I will edit the question with this image.

Comment: If you are using internet, you have explicitly enabled public access to your RDS? Its an option in the RDS settings.

Comment: @Marcin, yeah I did.

Comment: We need to see the outbound rules of that security group to make sure the EC2 is allowed to communicate with the RDS on port 3306 (MySQL)

Comment: Actually, I put the IPv4 of the ec2 instance that I was configuring the WP on the browser, so It could open the Wordpress page to initiate the config.

Comment: @Andre.IDK u mean the ec2 instance that I was configuring the WP?

Comment: You just posted the Inbound rules of the Security Group linked to the EC2 on which you have WP. We need to see the Outbound rules or at least that you can confirm there’s an entry that says this SG allows traffic on ports 3306 towards the RDS instance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the info you provided it seems your RDS is publicly accessible via the internet and connections are going to be accepted from any host (you might want to restrict these later)

Assuming that your software setup (OS, php, MySQL libraries, Wordpress) is okay and you’re using the right parameters in the WP configuration (host, port, user, password, db).

One of the remaining issues might be that the Security Group attached to your EC2 instance doesn’t allow connectivity on port 3306 (MySQL) towards the IP Address of your RDS instance.

Comment: Just to guarantee, the host is the endpoint avaible in the rds, right? @Andre.IDK

Comment: Yes, the Security Group attached to your EC2 (the one with Wordpress on it), must allow outbound connections towards the IP of the RDS DB.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have:

- An Amazon EC2 instance
- An Amazon RDS instance

The typical security configuration would be:

- The Amazon RDS database configured as `Publicly Accessible = No`
- A Security Group (`EC2-SG`) on the Amazon EC2 instance that permits inbound traffic from your desired locations (eg port 22 for SSH), and default Outbound rules permitting all traffic outbound
- A Security Group (`RDS-SG`) on the Amazon RDS database instance that permits inbound traffic on port 3306 from `EC2-SG`

That is, `RDS-SG` should specifically reference `EC2-SG` to permit the inbound connection.

[image: Security Group referencing another Security Group]

The app running on the EC2 instance should reference the RDS database via the DNS Name shown in the RDS console.

Comment: I have my RDS and EC2 instance at the same SG and I set in and outbound to all traffic to anywhere, shoudn't it be enough?

Comment: No. Security Groups are applied individually to each resource. If two resources have the same security group, then it would require an additional rule to "allow the security group to talk to itself". It is better to use two separate security groups (as shown above) since the EC2 instance and the RDS database instance actually require different rules. It would be less-secure to use the same security group for both resources.

Comment: So
I create a RDS SG with TCP inbound with port 3306 and specify the ipv4 of de WP Ec2.
And I edit my RDS DB and on security group I added this RDS SG and the Ec2 SG

That's it right?

Comment: Almost. The RDS security group should refer to the **Security Group** that is associated with the EC2 instance (`EC2-SG`), _not_ the IP address. This way, any future EC2 instance that uses that Security Group can _also_ access the RDS instance. Also, if the instance is replaced and gets a new IP address, it will still be able to connect since it uses the same security group.

Comment: I have added a picture showing how one Security Group can reference another. If this does not work, test it by temporarily changing the source to `0.0.0.0/0`, which will allow all inbound traffic. If that still does not work, then the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Still does not work : ( .
The DB_Host is something like this " database-1.cbompj2of.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com"?

Comment: From the EC2 instance, if you try `ping database-1.cbompj2of.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com`, does it return a private IP address (in the range of the VPC), or a public IP address (outside the VPC range)? Is the database set as `Publicly Available = Yes`?